# Chain contact on rear triangle

Tags: chainring, framebuilding, chainline

Hi can anyone help with some advice. I have built up a 2007 specialized big hit 2 and fitted it with a 32t narrow wide chain ring as that is what I've been used to riding. It rides great it handles great...but today I have noticed that the lower edge of the chain grinds into the rear triangle with very little clearance. Bearing in mind I am running it with an E13 SRS 32 chain device and shimano zee short cage derailleur. Is there a simple way round this or do I need to run a larger chain ring for more frame clearance. Any pointers would be great thanks.

Comment: Where exactly is it rubbing on the frame. The "rear triangle" is not a very precise location.

Comment: Hi its just where the chain leaves the lower side of the chain ring (about a 10mm patch of the frame) at the part of the rear triangle closest to the crankset

Comment: Photos (multiple angles) would help as it's unclear as to whether your wheel/cassette is twisted or something else is going on. Is this bicycle stock or did you modify it?

Comment: I don't known how to upload photos here I've been trying to though. I built the entire bike myself from parts up. Stock I the 07 model came with a 36t chainring

Comment: Upload the photos to imgur and then post the links. Someone can edit them inline into your question.

Comment: Also, is this happening constantly or only when you're doing jumps or something else that would cause chain slap?

Answer (score 2):

32 teeth should be enough to clear the frame.  Even using a 30 Tooth (pictured below) there is still plenty of frame clearance. That's a different frame, but still, it looks like there would be plenty of room on any frame.

[image: 30 Tooth Chainring]

The following picture shows a 2010 Big Hit with a 32 tooth chainring, and you can see there is ample frame clearance. The chain device actually has to bring the chain closer to the frame. Perhaps your chain device what's causing the problem and it is bringing the chain too close to the frame. You should be able to use the bike without the chain guide as the narrow wide chainring should be enough to keep the chain on there by itself. or perhaps use a different chain guide that mounts on the top.

[image]

Comment: In your big hit photo on the lower chain stay near the crank on the welding that you can see in photo if you zoom it in that's where my chain is scraping. Stock the frame had a 36t chain ring and my model the chain stays are lower then in your photo with different suspension design

Comment: The cheap fix would be to wrap an old inner tube around it so that it doesn't cause actual wear on the frame, and just check it every so often so that it doesn't wear through.